# Find all values from a column that corespond to the same value from anotehr column in R

Tags: r

I have a table like this

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("rs1544968", "rs1544968", "rs1544968", "rs1544968", 
"rs1544968", "rs1544968", "rs1544968", "rs1544968", "rs1544968", 
"rs1544968", "rs60296873", "rs60296873", "rs2811442", "rs2811442", 
"rs2811442", "rs2811442"), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), C = c("2.37E+08", "2,37E+08", 
"2.37E+08", "2,37E+08", "2.37E+08", "2,37E+08", "2.37E+08", "2,37E+08", 
"2.37E+08", "2,37E+08", "33171937", "33171937", "1,3E+08", "1,3E+08", 
"1,3E+08", "1,3E+08"), D = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), E = c("G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G"), F = c("ENSG00000116984", "ENSG00000186197", "ENSG00000119285", 
"ENSG00000077522", "ENSG00000077522", "ENSG00000116977", "ENSG00000244020", 
"ENSG00000086619", "ENSG00000198626", "ENSG00000077585", "ENSG00000150093", 
"ENSG00000099250", "ENSG00000172765", "ENSG00000170893", "ENSG00000172765", 
"ENSG00000170893")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

How can I collect all genes from the column
6 that correspond to each value in column 1?

For example, I would like to have :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could first group and then use `toString`:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0

df %>% 
  summarise(F = toString(F), .by = c(A, B, C, E))
```

```
# Groups:   A, B, C [4]
  A              B C        E     F                                                                           
  <chr>      <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>                                                                       
1 rs1544968      1 2,37E+08 G     ENSG00000186197, ENSG00000077522, ENSG00000116977, ENSG00000086619, ENSG000…
2 rs1544968      1 2.37E+08 G     ENSG00000116984, ENSG00000119285, ENSG00000077522, ENSG00000244020, ENSG000…
3 rs2811442      3 1,3E+08  G     ENSG00000172765, ENSG00000170893, ENSG00000172765, ENSG00000170893          
4 rs60296873    10 33171937 G     ENSG00000150093, ENSG00000099250
```

Comment: What if we want to do the oposite and for each geneID to collect all rsits? for example if we have one gene ENSG00000186197 with multiple rs1544968 , rs2811442   ?

Comment: Then just change the column names. Instead of F then you use A and in .by you use F instead of A. The letters are just placeholders for your column names. the `.by=` is new in dplyr and replaces the older (dplyr < 1.1.0) version of grouping: `..group_by (A, B, C, D) %>% ...... %>% ungroup()`